# Relative path on php

Tags: php, wordpress, require, mybb

I'm using a free hosting, I installed wordpress and mybb and I'm integrating both , so in the public_html I got the wp stuff and the forum directory, I'm making a template for wordpress so I need to use the directory /public_html/wp-content/themes/thetheme/somepage.php and require que file global.php in the /public_html/forum directory, I'm using this:

```
require_once '../../../foro/global.php';
```

For some reason It don't work, some help here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative paths in PHP not working on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221787/relative-paths-in-php-not-working-on-server)

Comment: You forgot an `m` in your code. Might be a mistake by copying here or you didn't notice

Comment: use absolute paths like  `require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/your/dirs/file.php");`

Comment: in my experience, the most reliable way if you want to mess with paths is to use `realpath(__DIR__) . '/../../relative/to/file.php';`. The magic `__DIR__` constant will yield the directory the file in question is stored in, `realpath` handles symlinks and the likes, which you should avoid whenever possible anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using relative paths can cause some issues, you may be able to solve this by finding the absolute path. You can find the absolute path of a particular file using the `getcwd()` function in PHP. Then simple just use `require_once` with a slash in front to get directly to the directory in question.

Comment: I used this and I finally got the path but when I use it, it just don't work do you see a mistake?                                                                      require_once '/hosting/www/conjusticia.com/public/foro/global.php';

Comment: Try putting something in global.php and see if it runs when you execute the page you require it in. Is the require_once calling a fatal error?

Comment: Ah, I see; the require is working completely fine; the problem is perhaps the same file has been included before and it's trying to redeclare a function with the same name as one which has already been declared.

Comment: Then this is the correct anwser, I just need to figure it out what to do now... Thanks

Comment: Thanks. :) My advice is to trace it back; see where else the function is declared, once you find that you can find where the function is being created twice.